# Vmware dll on .Net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, vmware

I have been using VMware.Vim.dll and VimService.dll in my C# Project with 4.6.2 Framework.

Now moving to .Net Core 2.0 I am trying to find a way to do the same and could not find something online. 
Here a piece of code for example:

```
                VimClientImpl client = new VimClientImpl();
                var serviceContent = client.Connect("urlConnection");
                var userSession = client.Login("userName","Password");

                List<VMware.Vim.EntityViewBase> vms = client.FindEntityViews(typeof(VMware.Vim.VirtualMachine), 
                null,filter, null);
                return vms;
```

If there is no Vmware dll that supports .Net Core 2.0, my other alternatives would be using Python script, or even Java.

Any Ideas?

Comment: First and foremost: You can reference .NET Framework libraries from .NET Core 2.0 (`netcoreapp2.0`) projects. Second, it only works when `VimService.dll` doesn't use any APIs  unavailable in .NET Standard 2.0. To find out if it uses such APIs or not, use the [.NET Portability Analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/portability-analyzer). Dunno if that sufficiently answers your question. If yes, I'd post it as answer

Comment: @Tseng It is not answering my question because I know this dll is not compatible with .NET Core 2.0.

Comment: Did you run the .NET Portability Analyzer? Only then you are certain it uses or doesn't uses APIs not available in .NET Standard. This ability was added to be able to use dlls which were not ported or cross compiled to .NET Standard yet (i.e. abandoned project) , but may be API compatible even if it doesn't explicitly targets .NET Standard 2.0. But if it really uses API which isn't there in .NET Standard 2.0, then you'll likely have to target .NET Framework (you can still use ASP.NET Core 2 though) and either target Mono on non-Windows platforms or keep it Windows only until there is a port